# AppendLine and replacing

Tags: vb.net, replace, stringbuilder

I want to get my output from

```
223-F456
```

to

```
223-F456

223-F456#

223-F4560

223-#456
```

I've done simple code for this but only adding #,0 to the ends of lines works:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
            sb.AppendLine(line)
            sb.AppendLine(line & "#")
            sb.AppendLine(line & "0")
            sb.Replace(line.LastIndexOf("-") + 1, "#") -> this doesn't work 
        Next
        TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
```

output:

```
223-F456

223-F456#

223-F4560
```

The letter is not always "F": I want to replace first letter after "-" not replace "F", also might some serials have "F" letter that not what I want.

Simple products serial in shop but replacing the string after "-" doesn't work and doesn't show, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the F *always* an F?

Comment: @AndrewMorton nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.8) and [String.Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.8) like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
        sb.AppendLine(line)
        sb.AppendLine(line & "#")
        sb.AppendLine(line & "0")
        Dim replaceAt = line.LastIndexOf("-") + 1
        sb.AppendLine(line.Remove(replaceAt, 1).Insert(replaceAt, "#"))
    Next

    TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString()

End Sub
```

Or if you preferred then you could use the [String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) function:

```
    sb.AppendLine(line.Substring(0, replaceAt) & "#" & line.Substring(replaceAt + 1))
```

It would also be possible to use a regular expression to do the replace, I expect someone else could come up with a better regex, but this works:

```
    Dim re As New Regex("(.*-)([^-])(.*)")
    For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
        ' ...
        sb.AppendLine(re.Replace(line, "$1#$3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
line.LastIndexOf("-") + 1
```

will return a number (indicating the place in `line` where it found the last `-` character, plus one).

But the replace function expects you to tell it what string you want to replace. You want to replace `F`, not a number. (Your current code would resolve to `sb.Replace(4, "#")`, which clearly won't find any `4`s to replace.)

And if you do `sb.Replace` it'll replace it for all the versions of the string you've previously added to the stringbuilder. Therefore, it would make more sense to replace it in `line`, and then append that modified version of `line` to the stringbuilder.

```
sb.AppendLine(line.Replace("F", "#"))
```

Live demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5BZAUg

---

Edit:

If you need to replace any character following the `-`, not specifically an `F`, you can do it by finding the character index in `line`, and then removing the character at that index and replacing it with another one, e.g.

```
Dim index = line.LastIndexOf("-") + 1
sb.AppendLine(line.Remove(index, 1).Insert(index, "#"))
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RTbiUG

Comment: the letter not always F i want to replace first letter after (-) not replace F , also might some serials have F letter that not what i want @ADyson

Comment: Ok. You didn't make that very clear really. I've updated the answer which a version to take account of that.